# One liner renaming a group of files and directories

Tags: java, bash

I have a java project with the following naming convention {project-prefix}-{project type} such that we end up with:

- files like prefix-type.xml, etc.
- directories like com/organization/prefix-type/.
- java files like /com/organization/prefix-type/PrefixFactory.java

I'm looking for a bash one liner that will rename the {project-prefix} portion of all of the files and directories in java project(*.java, *.xml, etc.) bonus points if it can handle the camel-case java files and/or extend the find/replace to the contents of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-exec` option of `find` to execute a command in which you can use the name of the current matched file/directory (expanded with "{}"), something like:

```
find <directory> -iname <pattern> -exec mv "{}" $(modify {} whenever you want) \;
```

Comment: I'm a little mystified about what is going on in the $(modify {} whenever you want) section can you elaborate and perhaps provide an example?